# Android threads locking using synchronized

Tags: android

I'm trying to use locks in Android to detect when the activity is active or not, the flow of my app is below,

I'm using threads running by service and I have one activity.
The thread will check if the Activity is open or not,

```
1- If it is open/active then it will NOT update the DB. 
2- If the activity/active isn't open then it will update the DB.
```

Is the below code correct,

On the activity side I'm doing this,

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    GlobalVars.setActivityActive()

}
```

On the thread side I'm doing this,

```
if (GlobalVars.isActivityActive())
   do nothing
else
   update DB
```

And the global vars class is this

```
public class GlobalVars extends Application {

    private boolean ActivityActive;

    public boolean isActivityActive() {
        synchronized (this) {
            return ActivityActive;
        }
    }

    public void setActivityActive(boolean ActivityActive) {
        synchronized (this) {
            this.ActivityActive = ActivityActive;
        }
    }

}
```

My question is this, is using synchronized in the get correct? or should I just do this,

```
public boolean isActivityActive() {

        return ActivityActive;

}
```

**Update**

This is how I ended up using it based on the answers/comments

```
    private volatile boolean activityActive;// this would be enough to be thread safe
```

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: `synchronized` won't do anything here. However, you'd want to declare `ActivityActive` as `volatile` to make sure all threads get the most recent version of it. Side-note: Member names should be lower-case, so it ought to be `activityActive`, or better yet, `mActivityActive` to render it more readable to other java developers.

Comment: @323go is correct.  If you make activityActive volatile, there is no point in synchronizing the method.  ... and I repeat: just use an AtomicBoolean.

Comment: Thanks, updated based on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, that will work.

It's crazy, though.  If you are gonna synchronize on "this" you could make it simpler by just synchronizing the methods.  ... so what is that `ReentrantLock` for?

... and you could make the whole thing even *simpler* by just using an AtomicBoolean.

Comment: ReentrantLock is there by mistake, I was experimenting. how can synchronize the method?

Comment: I just found out how to do it, thanks for the guidance.